# Site Logo is overriding my post featured image on Social Media

Tags: themes, post-thumbnails, social-sharing

Using my site logo is necessary for my website header/header image to propagate properly on all formats. Unfortunately, when active, it overrides any featured image for a new post whenever the post is shared on on social media.

As soon as the site logo is turned off, the featured image shows up properly on a shared post. Newsup/Newsup Pro (active site/sandbox site) are the themes my site(s) respectively use. What is the work around or is there something extremely obvious that Im missing?

Comment: Additionally, I'm not sure if it just takes time to propagate through search engines before the thumbnail shows up, and its just my impatience that is the issue.

Comment: there are debuggers provided by the social media network sites that can flush the cache and tell you where they got the image from, the FB debugger tool is quite popular, but, i wouldn't say that the site logo is overriding the featured image, it's much more likely that the featured image is simply never being set as the social media image ( aka the opengraph tags ), unfortunately there's no code and no debugging information in your question to work with. It's very likely that theme doesn't set one and they're just using the first image tag they come across which is the site logo in the header